# Debian GNU parted

Tags: linux, hard-drive, partitioning, debian

I have an internal SATA hard drive which is 4TB. When installing Debian Wheezy, the installer saw it as a 2.2TB drive. I was told to use GNU parted to set up GPT on the partition I wanted, so I set up the initial partitions as follows: 
/ - 50GB 
swap - 10GB 
/raid - 2.14TB  ext4 (this is the partition in question)

Running `fdisk -l` lists the following partitions:
/dev/sda1 (boot) 
/dev/sda2 (swap) 
/dev/sda3 (presumably the partition for /raid)

I ran `parted /dev/sda3` followed by `mklabel gpt`. The second command gave me an error which read something along the lines of: 
"Error: Partition(s) 1, 2, 3, .... , 64 on /dev/sda3 have been written, but we have been unable to inform the kernel of the change, probably because it/they are in use. As a result, the old partition(s) will remain in use. You should reboot now before making further changes."

The above message is produced whenever I execute `mkpart` as well. Furthermore, when executing `mkpart`, I can't seem to specify a size beyond 2.14TB, even if I specify `End` to be 100%.

So, to sum up: What do I need to do to get my 4TB - 50GB (for /) - 10GB (for swap) = 3.94TB (roughly)?

My kernel version is:
3.2.0-4-686-pae

Comment: Try `cfdisk` instead of `fdisk`.

Comment: Follow the advice you reported from `parted`: `You should reboot now before making further changes`. Also, `cfdisk` won't help; both `cfdisk` and `fdisk` are tools for managing the old [Master Boot Record (MBR)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_boot_record) partitioning system, whereas you need to use the new [GUID Partition Table (GPT)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID_Partition_Table) system. To use GPT, you need to use either something based on libparted (`parted`, GParted, etc.), or something in the GPT fdisk family (`gdisk`, `cgdisk`, or `sgdisk`).

Answer (score 2):

GPT is a partition table for the whole disk, not for a single partition in MBR partition table. So using parted you can do:

```
parted /dev/sda
mklabel gpt
mkpart ...
mkpart ...
mkpart ...
```

Comment: Since I only have a single disk, does that mean all my data gets wiped out by running parted on it? If that's the case then let me get this right. The sequence of steps to switch from MBR to GPT for a single disk setup is: install the OS, run parted (which will wipe out the OS), install OS again. Is that correct?

Comment: Update: Ran gdisk which merged all three partitions (sda1, sda2, sda3) into one (sda1) and claimed it to be GPT. Now I can no longer boot and the system stops at the message: "PXE-E53: No boot filename received"

Comment: My system is 32 bit. Is it even possible to use UEFI? According to the Debian Wheezy release notes, UEFI is supported for 64 bit systems. It doesn't say anything about 32 bit systems.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old thread, but still important. In answer to your single disk question.  You should boot off of a live cd to run parted.  This should allow you to convert the MBR to GPT on the unmounted single disk.  Parted does not necessarily wipe out the data on the drive unless you use something like mkfs or change the limits to exclude where the OS is. Some examples can be found at
http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2011/09/parted-command-examples/
Once you have converted the MBR to GPT, you will have to add the partition information. Read about mklabel and rescue at
http://www.gnu.org/software/parted/manual/parted.html