# Using GPT but still restricted by the 2.2TB limit

Tags: hard-drive, partitioning, debian, raid

As my other thread ([Debian GNU parted](https://superuser.com/questions/626150/debian-gnu-parted)) doesn't seem to be getting any responses and my situation has changed considerably, I thought I'd ask a new question.

I followed this article:
http://www.anchor.com.au/blog/2012/10/booting-large-gpt-disks-without-efi/

I did so by running parted from the PartedMagic Live CD and setting up the partitions as suggested in that article: a 1MB bios_grub partition starting at 1MB and ending at 2MB and a root partition (ext4) starting at 2MB and ending at 100%. I then installed Debian Wheezy from the Debian Live CD. Upon installation, running `fdisk -l` reports it to be a GPT file system and parted recognizes both the partitions created earlier. However, regardless of what tool I use (fdisk, parted, gdisk), the root partition shows a capacity of 2.19TB.

I have a 32-bit system (a DELL PowerEdge R200 server) that does not have UEFI. The system consists of a RAID controller set up to use RAID0 with two 4TB disks.

So, my question is:
Is it even possible to access the entire 4TB using software alone (i.e, parted, gdisk, etc)? I.e, do I need additional hardware?

Comment: Which RAID controller are you using? You need one with LBA64 support.

Comment: I can't access the server to see which RAID controller is being used but I will check that and get back to you tomorrow. In the mean time, could you please elaborate a bit more on this 'LBA64' thing? I've tried Googling but can't get any useful info. I find the number 64 especially troublesome. Will a LBA64 RAID controller be compatible with a 32 bit processor?

Comment: LBA stands for [Logical block addressing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_block_addressing). I'd imagine it's compatible 32-bit systems, but I'm not sure, I've been using 64-bit hardware for a while now, and I've never used a drive larger than 1.5TB. You could also give something like FlexRAID a shot.

Comment: Thanks Robert. As it turns out, my RAID controller did not have LBA64, so I removed it and have plugged both my hard drives straight into the motherboard. They are now recognized as 4TB drives and I am using software RAID instead. If you like, you could sum all this up in an 'answer' and I can then accept it as a solution.

Comment: Wrote up an answer. Glad I could be of help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your RAID controller likely does not support LBA64, 32-bit sectors create a ~2TB capacity limit. LBA stands for [Logical Block Addressing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_block_addressing) and is the way hard drive blocks are accessed.

The solution is to either get a new RAID controller with support. You can also see if your motherboard directly supports >2TB drives, which was the solution in your case, as you mentioned in your comment.